# Sitecore Experience Editor does not work for the fields rendering inside foreach loop

Tags: experience-editor

Trying to make a component experience editable. However, having some issues with Fields those are getting rendered through loop.

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Child items will not editable you need to use `Edit Frame`:

**Edit Frame**

With an edit frame you can surround a section of html within your view with a clickable target, that will display a toolbar with a button to launch the dialogue.

To set up an edit frame:

- In the core database navigate to /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons and create a new item based on Edit Frame Button Folder. This folder will be referenced in your view for the collection of buttons to be displayed.
- Under the new folder create a new item based on Field Editor Button and give it the name of your button.
- On your button item make sure you set an icon and the list of fields the button should allow the content editor to edit. These should be pipe separated.

[image]

- In Visual Studio open the view for your rendering
- Add a reference to Sitecore.Mvc.Extensions
- Surround the section to show the button with a using block as follows:

```
@using (Html.BeginEditFrame(RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem.Paths.FullPath, "Button Folder Name", "Toolbar Title"))
{
    // HTML here
}
```

You can use `@testimonial.Description` and child content will be editable through `Edit Frame`

More detail available here https://himynameistim.com/blog/custom-experience-buttons-vs-edit-frames-in-sitecore

Comment: Thanks a lot Swati. Now its working for me. Just want to update one thing here,
@using (Html.BeginEditFrame(RenderingContext.Current.ContextItem.Paths.FullPath, "ID of Button Folder Name"))
{
    // HTML here
}

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using the combination of edit frames, experience editor buttons, and field renderers. You need to follow the below steps.

- Making the Controller Rendering
- Code your View
- Adding Edit Frames and Buttons

Here is the article you can follow that does the same thing but for the Carousel component. You can follow this example and customize your own component.

https://www.techguilds.com/blog/rendering-multiple-child-items-in-one-component-in-sitecore

Comment: Thanks a lot Sumit. Both yours and Swati's input helped me to resolve the issue.